# Postgres configuration for high-latency storage

Tags: postgresql, performance, storage, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to setup a postgres server using Ceph as storage. After taking benchmarks, it was obvious that even though the storage has a really good throughput, the higher latency brought by network and Ceph (~15ms vs <0.1ms for a normal SSD storage) creates a huge bottleneck.

A setting of `fsync = off` improves performance tremendously, but of course, is not a viable solution since it may create data corruptions in case of power outage, etc. There is also `wal_sync_method`, but even though changing it improves TPM a bit, its effect are negligible.

How can I configure the Postgres or change the design of my system (e.g. using different storage for WAL and data) to improve performance?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what is the O.S environment with their version(x,y,z)?

Comment: I have no experience with Ceph but I have read that it’s possible to use a local cache with it.

Comment: Are the benchmarks you ran relevant to your expected use case?  I think that more people are limited by read than by single-threaded fsync.

Comment: Why are you using Ceph?  You might be able to get around the slow fsync by putting WAL on local disk, but that might defeat the whole purpose of using Ceph in the first place.  Depending on what that purpose is.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan The Postgres itself is ran on a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @jjanes Sure, but since we are trying to create a multi-purpose system, it's important to optimize each aspect of performance.

Comment: @jjanes We are using Ceph as the reliable storage for our Kubernetes cluster. So, we are kinda limited in our choices (we'll consider other choices if the problem doesn't get solved though)